# How to get Multiple Result Sets in asp.net MVC4 by complex type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Visual studio 2012 with .Net Framework 4.5

I am geting Multiple Result set from My store procedure 'PROC_GetDashDDLData'

[Click to view image of store procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBrxH.png)

In Controller..How could i get Multiple result set from Store Procedure

```
public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
    using (dbPA_MVCEntities objCon = new dbPA_MVCEntities())
    {
        List<PROC_GetDashDDLData_Result> AllResult = objCon.PROC_GetDashDDLData().ToList<PROC_GetDashDDLData_Result>();
    }
    return View();
}
```

this is it in My Model.Context.cs file for return Result of SP

```
    public virtual ObjectResult<PROC_GetDashDDLData_Result> PROC_GetDashDDLData()
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<PROC_GetDashDDLData_Result>("PROC_GetDashDDLData");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to return multiple objects in the same method, you might want to take a look at "Tuple"

```
Tuple<int, string, bool> tuple = new Tuple<int, string, bool>(1, "cat", true);
```

Comment: how could i use it in Model.Context.cs file where i am return resultset?